# Poner las silabas en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy en la búsqueda de crear una función que tome una palabra que me ingrese el usuario y me devuelva una lista con sus silabas. La primer parte ya la logre, la de conseguir las silabas de la palabra que me ingresan. El problema que tengo ahora, es como puedo hacer que me agregue estas silabas a una lista. Ya que yo con el siguiente código, me las ingresa pero como un solo elemento. De esta forma:

```
['ca sa']
```

Y yo necesito que lo haga de esta forma:

```
 ["ca", "sa"]
```

El código que tengo para esta ultima parte de la función no es muy avanzado ya que me tope con este problema y no se como proseguir. Lo que escribi es esto:

```
def dameSilabas(candidata):
    lista=[]
    silabas=separador(candidata) #la funcion separador me separa las palabras por su silabas 
    lista.append(silabas)
    return lista
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: En vez de lista.append prueba con sílabas.split() y return silabas

Comment: que devuelve separador? que hay en la variable silabas? todo tu problema esta ahi...

Comment: Haz que `separador()` te devuelva la lista, en lugar de la cadena separada por espacios. Estoy por apostar que en `separador()` tienes incluso un `" ".join()` :-)

Comment: a tu comentario Adrian, si lo pongo de esa forma me devuelva "di no sa u rio", no esta adentro de una lista que es lo que necesito.

Comment: como puedo hacer que separador() me devuelva una lista?

Comment: ¿Cómo has hecho la función `separador()`? Muy probablemente ya está computando una lista

Comment: Si no tienes acceso a la función `separador()` porque forma parte de alguna otra librería que no puedes modificar, siempre puedes cambiar tu `lista.append(silabas)` por `lista.extend(silabas.split())`

Comment: GRACIAS!!! @abulafia